# Flutter OneSignal push notification issue

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I need to push notification from my WordPress blog to my flutter app using one signal plugin and it works fine to receive a notification when a new post added in my blog, So my problem is when i clicked on the notification in my Android phone it redirect me to post url, I need to open my app, not my site url.
please any can help me.

Comment: please show us what you have tried already

Comment: I find a solution by following OneSignals documentation and already can control what can i do when i receive a notification, And i found a code can send any thing with notification response except the url. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-wordpress-faq